# Want add-on to restart Firefox and show new page, but instead all old tabs are displayed

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'd like my add-on to restart Firefox and upon restart have a pre-defined webpage displayed.

When I restart the browser via `nsIAppStartup.quit()`, all of the tabs I had been viewing will be re-opened after restart.  I have tried to cope with this manually by closing all the tabs before restarting (see code below), but I find that although I can visually confirm that all of the tabs are closed, they will be present again after a restart.

I assume that some session restore mechanism is re-creating them after the restart.  I have found several preferences regarding "SessionStore" (`browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo`, `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash`, etc), but toggling them does not seem to help me resolve this issue.

How should I go about ensuring that the old tabs are closed after a restart?  Thank you!

```
// get gBrowser reference
var mainWindow = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
var gBrowser = mainWindow.gBrowser;

// build a collection of tabs to close
var tabsToClose = [];
for( var i = 0; i < gBrowser.mTabContainer.childNodes.length - 1; i++ ){
    tabsToClose.push( gBrowser.mTabContainer.childNodes[i] );
}

// Open homepage in new tab
gBrowser.addTab(DEFAULT_HOMEPAGE);

// Close all tabs except for homepage
for( var i = 0; i < tabsToClose.length; i++ ){      
    gBrowser.removeTab( tabsToClose[i] );
}

// restart browser
Cc["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"].getService(nsIAppStartup).quit(nsIAppStartup.eRestart | nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code a bit and came up with this solution:

```
var Cc = Components.classes;
var Ci = Components.interfaces;

var pref = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService);
pref.setBoolPref("browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs",false);

var mainWindow = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
var gBrowser = mainWindow.gBrowser;

var newTab = gBrowser.addTab("www.google.com");

// Easier solution than having two loops to identify the open tabs
gBrowser.removeAllTabsBut(newTab);

var nsIAppStartup = Ci.nsIAppStartup; // You were missing this part on your question
Cc["@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1"].getService(nsIAppStartup).quit(nsIAppStartup.eRestart | nsIAppStartup.eAttemptQuit);
```

The preference that you need to change is `browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs` so you don't get a warning when closing multiple tabs. The other sessionstore prefs i didn't touch.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Filipe for the refactor, that is indeed cleaner.  However, when I execute the plugin with this code I am still experiencing the same symptom.  After the browser restarts, all of my tabs have been restored.  When I comment out the `.quit()` call, I see that the tabs are in fact being closed.  Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Damn. you're right. It's not fully working. I don't know what i did for it to work, maybe some combination of removing the `quit()` and gave the impression of working. Anyway. You can try using the [sessionstore forgetClosedTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsISessionStore#forgetClosedTab) . I never used it myself. Or you can work around it and do the closing when firefox starts. This way you may have less problems.